# Angular - using ngModel.$parsers.push and forms

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am using `ngModel.$parsers.push` to change the user input:

```
ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
    //some logic here - changing the vaue
    //set the new value        
    ngModel.$setViewValue(value); 
    // renders the input with the new viewValue
    ngModel.$render();
    return ture; //in any case                
});
```

It works fine but it makes the `form` field `unvalid` and shows `form.invalid.parse` under it.

I have tried to return the `value` or nothing but it still does not work.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: why is the idea for use $parsers, validation?

Comment: edit the question - to change the value, is there another way?

Comment: change value of the model? of an input?

Comment: yes - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339667/angular-directive-to-change-input-values-on-insert

Comment: ng-model="user" in html ||| $scope.user='test' in controller >>> that's you need to do

Comment: not clear what you mean by controller - it is a custom directive.

Comment: there is Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [AngularDoc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

> Returning undefined from a parser means a parse error occurred. In
>   that case, no $validators will run and the ngModel will be set to
>   undefined unless ngModelOptions.allowInvalid is set to true. The parse
>   error is stored in ngModel.$error.parse.

Thus, try this in your input field

```
<input ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }" />
```